# Visual Studio Additional Include Directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, static-libraries, header-files

I have .sln with two projects: library (.lib) and project (.exe), which use this library.

Library uses external header and has path to it in Additional Include Directories, but I confused that I also should add path to this header to Project's Additional Include Directories.

Shouldn't it work like:
Library Additional Include Directories has all external paths and Project Additional Include Directories has only path to this Library?

Comment: Each project that uses those headers needs to know where they are. The library needs them to compile itself. The executable needs them in order to compile itself and link to the library.

Comment: There's a difference between external headers which appear in your library's headers, and external headers which appear only in your library's source files. The latter only need to be in your library project settings, the former need to be in both. Note there is nothing smart going on, VS will not deduce that your libraries path settings should be 'inherited' by your project, or anything like that.

Comment: Depending on your code you could design the library such that it does not expose the external dependency in its external interface. The PIMPL idiom helps with that.